# Unable to set tablet grid system in bootstrap - fiddle attached

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to arrange the bootstrap grid system for tablet version.
I have 15 boxes to be arranged. It is aligning perfectly for desktop and mobile, however not able to set it correct for tablet resolution. `col-sm-*`

```css
.newcss{
    background-color: red;
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px !important;
    border-right: 5px solid white;
    border-bottom: 5px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-1"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-lg-1 col-sm-2 newcss">
        <p>Box 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-lg-1 col-sm-2 newcss">
        <p>Box 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-lg-1 col-sm-2 newcss">
        <p>Box 3</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4 col-lg-1 col-sm-2 newcss">
        <p>Box 4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-lg-1 col-sm-2 newcss">
        <p>Box 5</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-1"></div>

    <div class="col-xs-4 col-lg-1 col-sm-2 newcss">
        <p>Box 6</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4 col-lg-1 col-sm-2 newcss">
        <p>Box 7</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-lg-1 col-sm-2 newcss">
        <p>Box 8</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-lg-1 col-sm-2 newcss">
        <p>Box 9</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4 col-lg-1 col-sm-2 newcss">
        <p>Box 10</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-1"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2 newcss">
        <p>Box 11</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-lg-1 col-sm-2 newcss">
        <p>Box 12</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4 col-lg-1 col-sm-2 newcss">
        <p>Box 13</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-lg-1 col-sm-2 newcss">
        <p>Box 14</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-lg-1 col-sm-2 newcss">
        <p>Box 15</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/zwgqekto/)

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap is based on a 12 column layout, so you are wrongly using the grid.
You can add some padding on the left and right sides of the content doing like this:

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/8253261k/)

```css
.newcss {
            background-color: red;
            height: 120px;
            width: 120px !important;
            border-right: 5px solid white;
            border-bottom: 5px solid white;
            float: left;
        }
```

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-1 col-xs-1"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">
            <div class="newcss">
                <p>Box 1</p>
            </div>
            <div class="newcss">
                <p>Box 2</p>
            </div>
            <div class="newcss">
                <p>Box 3</p>
            </div>
            <div class="newcss">
                <p>Box 4</p>
            </div>
            <div class="newcss">
                <p>Box 5</p>
            </div>
            <div class="newcss">
                <p>Box 6</p>
            </div>
            <div class="newcss">
                <p>Box 7</p>
            </div>
            <div class="newcss">
                <p>Box 8</p>
            </div>
            <div class="newcss">
                <p>Box 9</p>
            </div>
            <div class="newcss">
                <p>Box 10</p>
            </div>
            <div class="newcss">
                <p>Box 11</p>
            </div>
            <div class="newcss">
                <p>Box 12</p>
            </div>
            <div class="newcss">
                <p>Box 13</p>
            </div>
            <div class="newcss">
                <p>Box 14</p>
            </div>
            <div class="newcss">
                <p>Box 15</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-1 col-xs-1"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I wouldn't necessarily recommend using the grid system like you are (with forced, absolute heights and widths, as it kind of negates the point of having a responsive grid in the first place), it seems there is a simple solution to your immediate problem. You've got these bits of HTML stuck in the middle of the code in a couple of places.

`<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-1"></div>`

It contains no content and is having the effect of pushing your layout around. Get rid of those and it seems to work out you want to.

Comment: I have added these empty cushions to add uniform padding. More like the offset effect.